# Iterating over columns in a dataframe to run/append calculation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe sort of:

```
        Date       AAPL      NFLX       INTC  
0 2008-01-02  27.834286  3.764286  25.350000    
1 2008-01-03  27.847143  3.724286  24.670000    
2 2008-01-04  25.721428  3.515714  22.670000   
3 2008-01-07  25.377142  3.554286  22.879999    
4 2008-01-08  24.464285  3.328571  22.260000
```

I want to run .pct_change(1) to each of the stocks in each column, and append the 3 columns to the end of the df.

I know how to do it when I already know the name of the column, say AAPL. With that prior knowledge, I can do df['AAPL_Ret'] = df.AAPL.pct_change(1)

But eventually, I will have 100s of stocks in the file and the goal is to automate the calculations without having to individually type each stock ticker in the code. So I would have to iterate through all the columns and then run the .pct_change somehow.

Any ideas? Many thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One thing you can do is

```
for col in df.columns:
    if not isstock(col):
        continue
    df["{}_Ret".format(col)] = df[col].pct_change(1)
```

I've included the `isstock()` part because you have the date as a column rather than the index, and you don't want to take the percent change in the date (I presume). You can either define `isstock()` elsewhere or replace it in my code with whatever condition you want.

Comment: can you help me define isstock? have no idea how to approach that, tickers vary in length for example

Comment: @EksanaStasis You can either have inclusive criteria (something all tickers have in common e.g. if all tickers are all caps, do `col == col.upper()`), or exclusive criteria (something nothing tickers have, e.g. `col!='Date'`). Or, if Date is the only non-ticker column, you can just move it to the index.

Comment: Ok, I can try that. But also, would it be possible to iterate through the columns, something like for cols 3 to 6, say? so for col [3:6] in df.columns etc?

Comment: @EksanaStasis you can do `df.columns[3:6]`, but you have to make sure that the columns are in the order you're expecting.

Comment: That worked, thanks so much Accumulation. Appreciate your patience with a beginner like myself!

Comment: @EksanaStasis HOW is this different from either of the other answers, except for the fact that this is worse (because forced iteration)?

Comment: @CallCentreExecutive Do you think that the other answers somehow magically apply `pct_change` to all the columns without performing any iteration? I ran my code and found that it was more than three times as fast as yours. Plus it's more transparent and generalizable. My understanding is that the OP's main question was how to dynamically create column names, which I showed them with the `format` syntax. You provided code that *in this case*, provided the **results** they wanted, but didn't the explain the **concept** they were looking to understand.

Comment: Yes, because it's vectorised. I'll bet you didn't try this on anything larger than OP's dataframe.

Comment: @CallCentreExecutive Vectorization still uses iteration, albeit parallelized. And I tried it on a dataframe with 17 columns and over 200k rows.

Answer (score 3):

Call `pct_change` on the `DataFrame`, and then adding the result back becomes straightforward with `concat`.

```
df = df.set_index('Date')
pd.concat([df, df.pct_change(1).add_suffix('_Ret')], axis=1)

                 AAPL      NFLX       INTC  AAPL_Ret  NFLX_Ret  INTC_Ret
Date                                                                    
2008-01-02  27.834286  3.764286  25.350000       NaN       NaN       NaN
2008-01-03  27.847143  3.724286  24.670000  0.000462 -0.010626 -0.026824
2008-01-04  25.721428  3.515714  22.670000 -0.076335 -0.056003 -0.081070
2008-01-07  25.377142  3.554286  22.879999 -0.013385  0.010971  0.009263
2008-01-08  24.464285  3.328571  22.260000 -0.035972 -0.063505 -0.027098
```

The only thing to watch out for (and you've probably figured this out already) is that `pct_change` won't work if you have non-numeric columns.

Therefore, another (better) alternative would be

```
pd.concat([df, df.select_dtypes(exclude=[object]).pct_change(1)], 1)

         Date       AAPL      NFLX       INTC      AAPL      NFLX      INTC
0  2008-01-02  27.834286  3.764286  25.350000       NaN       NaN       NaN
1  2008-01-03  27.847143  3.724286  24.670000  0.000462 -0.010626 -0.026824
2  2008-01-04  25.721428  3.515714  22.670000 -0.076335 -0.056003 -0.081070
3  2008-01-07  25.377142  3.554286  22.879999 -0.013385  0.010971  0.009263
4  2008-01-08  24.464285  3.328571  22.260000 -0.035972 -0.063505 -0.027098
```

Which handles non-numeric columns gracefully when you have many of them.

OTOH, I would recommend setting the Date to the index in advance (and use option 1), because that's usually what you'd do when working with stock data. Not always though.

Comment: I like the selecting dtypes ... `df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number])`

Comment: @piRSquared Yup, that too!

Comment: ok guys, problem is I didn't tell the whole story re my df. After the stock tickers I also have some columns like 'day' and 'month end' that identify the last trading day of the month. My intention is to run the pct_change off of the last trading day of each month only. When I tried adding the code above it fails to add the columns

Comment: @EksanaStasis You can't not tell the whole story and then expect a single chapter to explain the entire plot. Sorry but that isn't good. Please open a new question with your details and hope that someone has the patience to answer you there.

Comment: Note that `pd.concat([df, df.pct_change(1).add_suffix('_Ret')], axis=1)` just *returns* the altered dataframe. To actually *set* the dataframe to the new version, you have to do `df =pd.concat([df, df.pct_change(1).add_suffix('_Ret')], axis=1)`

Comment: "You can't not tell the whole story and then expect a single chapter to explain the entire plot." While it's bad practice to not give all relevant details, it's also bad practice to write code that addresses only the highly specific situation that you *think* will apply.

Comment: @Acccumulation obviously, which is why you should aim to generalise to some extent. You should also not post a question and expect to receive an answer that solves world hunger.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the `period` argument to `pct_change` defaults to `1` and can be left out.

### `drop` the `'Date'` column

```
df.join(df.drop('Date', 1).pct_change().add_suffix('_Ret'))

        Date       AAPL      NFLX       INTC  AAPL_Ret  NFLX_Ret  INTC_Ret
0 2008-01-02  27.834286  3.764286  25.350000       NaN       NaN       NaN
1 2008-01-03  27.847143  3.724286  24.670000  0.000462 -0.010626 -0.026824
2 2008-01-04  25.721428  3.515714  22.670000 -0.076335 -0.056003 -0.081070
3 2008-01-07  25.377142  3.554286  22.879999 -0.013385  0.010971  0.009263
4 2008-01-08  24.464285  3.328571  22.260000 -0.035972 -0.063505 -0.027098
```

---

## `set_index`

```
df.join(df.set_index('Date').pct_change().add_suffix('_Ret'), on='Date')

        Date       AAPL      NFLX       INTC  AAPL_Ret  NFLX_Ret  INTC_Ret
0 2008-01-02  27.834286  3.764286  25.350000       NaN       NaN       NaN
1 2008-01-03  27.847143  3.724286  24.670000  0.000462 -0.010626 -0.026824
2 2008-01-04  25.721428  3.515714  22.670000 -0.076335 -0.056003 -0.081070
3 2008-01-07  25.377142  3.554286  22.879999 -0.013385  0.010971  0.009263
4 2008-01-08  24.464285  3.328571  22.260000 -0.035972 -0.063505 -0.027098
```